# How to return object method properly

Tags: javascript

I created `MyObject` in javascript and I need to return its method like this

```
var m = new MyObject();
document.onclick = m.myMethod;
```

But the problem is, all the `m` instance variables appear to be undefined, I can't access them (even though they are defined on `m`) and operations on them result in `NaN`. How do I do this properly, so instance variables stay set when method is executed?

Comment: Can you specify the MyObject code?

Comment: Is it as simple as you forgetting to use the `new` keyword? `var m = new MyObject();`?

Comment: EDIT: added "new" which was not in post, but was in code, so it is not the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the `this` scope is the html element, not the instance.

Either a closure

```
document.onclick = function(evt) { m.myMethod(evt); }
```

or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
document.onclick = m.myMethod.bind(m);
```

is needed to maintain the scope you are after.